# this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl is not showing anything on SharePoint Online Web Part

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a React based SharePoint Online Web Part and at one point I want to read items from a list.
However I get nothing back and the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'web')
```

Is this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl the correct way to do it?

```
public async getListData()
  {
    console.log('this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl:' + this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    let web = Web(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    const items: ISPItem[] = [];

    const itemsFromList: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle("theURLs").items.get();
    await itemsFromList.forEach(async item => {
      console.log('attempt push of ' + item["Title"]);
      console.log('attempt push of ' + item["Description"]);
      await items.push(
        {
          title: item["Title"],
          description: item["Description"]
        }
      )
    })

    await this.setState({ allItems: items, paginatedItems: items.slice(0, pageSize) });

  }
```

Comment: Can you console log this `this.context` OR `this.context.pageContext`? what is the output?

Comment: Is the error in the line where you create the web or is it the line where you want to use it? Both, the property and your variable are called web. And are you using pnp v2?